# Why is npm looking for node in the wrong place? /usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, yarnpkg

I know I can "fix" this issue with a symlink or some such hack. What I want to know is how can I fix this issue without hacking my system. Why is npm unable to find node where it is?

I have an old JS project I'm trying to update to TS.

When, [per the docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/), I run the following, I get the error you see:

```
$ sudo npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
```

Of course, there is no `/usr/bin/env/node` in my system:

```
$ /usr/bin/env/node -v
-bash: /usr/bin/env/node: Not a directory
```

I use `nvm`, so:

```
$ nvm -v
0.39.5
$ nvm ls
       v14.20.0
->     v16.16.0
default -> node (-> v16.16.0)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v16.16.0) (default)
stable -> 16.16 (-> v16.16.0) (default)
lts/* -> lts/hydrogen (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.24.1 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.22.12 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.21.3 (-> N/A)
lts/gallium -> v16.20.2 (-> N/A)
lts/hydrogen -> v18.17.1 (-> N/A)
$ which npm
/home/xxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/bin/npm
$ npm --version
8.11.0
$ which node
/home/xxxxx/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/bin/node
$ node -v
v16.16.0
```

I even, [per the docs](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating), updated nvm (and restarted my shell) for kicks:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.5/install.sh | bash
```

So, why is npm trying looking for `/usr/bin/env/node`? How can I non-hackily fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had originally used `yarn` on this project, not `npm`, even though I use npm on other projects (why? sigh). Installing with yarn worked:

```
$ yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

I finally noticed this because of the `yarn.lock` file at the project root.